# Why does my VScode not work when I input scanf?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, scanf

So I'm new to coding overall and I'm using VScode, but in one of the user input tutorial I'm watching require the use of scanf(), but for some reason my code refuses to work, can someone help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int Age;
    {
    printf("Enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Age);
    printf("you are %d years old", Age);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and after I press the run code button, all I get is just

[Running] cd "/Users/Spanecon/IDK WTF/" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/Spanecon/IDK WTF/"tempCodeRunnerFile

but nothing else comes up.  Can someone help me please?

Comment: I suspect your `tasks.json` configuration isn't correctly setup. If the output is verbatim what you show, you are missing the closing `'"'` when you attempt to run the script. See [Get Started with C++ and Mingw-w64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: It seems like the MSYS2 in the article is only available to Window user, do you have any other suggestion which is similar to it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are running on, but [Using C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) and there is a similar page for Mac.

Comment: I'm currently running on Mac, but I found the problem, I just needed to tick the box in VScode saying to run the code internally, and it works wonder! I still have another problem though, when I write my code in a new tab, it runs fine, but if I save it and then run it again, it gives me an error: "no such file or directory" and "no input file"

Comment: No clue there. I gave up fighting with IDEs a long time ago. Much simpler just to choose your favorite editor and open a terminal and compile and run from the command line. No guess work involved, and you learn exactly what is required to build and run your projects -- then you can tell an IDE how you want it done. VS Code is a good tool, but it takes almost as much to learn its idiosyncrasies as it does to learn the basic syntax of any language. Especially if you are not already familiar with json.

Comment: xD, thank you anyway for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since input is required, you could install the [Code Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) for this.

Set it to run code in the terminal through an option in settings.json:

```json
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
}
```

To run the code, right click and select "Run Code" (Ctrl + Alt + N). Enter the input in the terminal thereafter.